# Switch from clone to new fork preserving changes

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

I cloned a remote repository from BitBucket, made changes (without pushing/committing anything).  I've decided that it would be better to modify a fork than the original.  I've just created a fork on BitBucket --- but how do I change my local version to work with the new fork *instead* of the original source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *need* to change anything you just push and pull from your fork instead of the original.

For example if the original is:

https://bitbucket.org/SomeProject/SomeProject

and your fork is:

https://bitbucket.org/MyUserName/SomeProject

and you did:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/SomeProject/SomeProject
```

then you can do:

```
hg push https://bitbucket.org/MyUserName/SomeProject
hg pull https://bitbucket.org/MyUserName/SomeProject
```

However usually one sets the default path to save specifying the repo for each push and pull. To Change this either use the Synchronization tab in [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) or edit the projects .hg/hgrc file.

the [hgrc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) will prolly look like this:

```
[paths]
default = https://bitbucket.org/SomeProject/SomeProject
```

change it to:

```
[paths]
default = https://bitbucket.org/MyUserName/SomeProject
```

Comment: Great answer. I would just add that you can define extra shortcuts in the `[paths]` section. So you can add `upstream = https://bitbucket.org/SomeProject/SomeProject` and then begin using `hg pull upstream` to get the latest changes from the upstream repository.